# (Android) How to style action bar with pattern

Tags: java, android, xml, design-patterns, android-actionbar

I need to style my Android actionbar in similar way ([***EXAMPLE***](http://oi61.tinypic.com/2150vmb.jpg)).
I know that this is iOS version and it isn't suits to Android guidelines, but this is my task. 
I also know I cant change color of status bar, my goal is only to style action bar.
I would appreciate for any tips how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to change the ActionBar, create a custom one of your preference.

**First** create an XML layout on how your custom ActionBar should look like. Here make sure you add an ID to the container layout (Linear Layout). The will be required at the later steps.

**Second** Inflate the XML layout created in you java code onCreate method as follows,

```
LinearLayout myTitleBar = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.the_id_you_set_in_first_step);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.name_of_custom_xml_layout); //note that here its the layout name you set
```

**Note:** As you are dealing with ActionBar, your application theme should be set to *Theme.AppCompat.Light*

To learn more about them, have a look at this quick video tutorials demonstrating the same.

[Part One - 5min](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UVSSGaWGkzA&list=PLlxmoA0rQ-LyCGSSD_nuPAmXDSR_FU0RR&index=62)

[Second Part - 9min](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eW85amUN2cQ&list=PLlxmoA0rQ-LyCGSSD_nuPAmXDSR_FU0RR&index=63)

[Third Part](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=js3_b0e0WWE&list=PLlxmoA0rQ-LyCGSSD_nuPAmXDSR_FU0RR&index=64)

Hope it helps!