# Where can I find the default styles for Theme.AppCompat.Light?

Tags: android

I'm trying to customize a theme that extends `Theme.AppCompat.Light`. I'm not sure which values I need to change specifically, for instance:

- Action bar text color
- Default window / view background color

I'm using the new `android.support.v7.widget.ToolBar` for my action bar so normal values like `android:actionBarStyle` don't seem to be working on it.

I'd like to just see a list of default properties and values for each style so I can at least look up which attribute I need to change.

Thanks!

Comment: If you would like to create a customized action bar, refer my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26439715/android-how-to-style-action-bar-with-pattern/26441088#26441088

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you are using Android Studio then it would be easy to track down default/in-build resources/styles. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and take your cursor onto the `Theme.AppCompat.Light` and click on it will take you to that `values.xml` file.

You will find below styles:

```
 <style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light" />

 <style name="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light" parent="Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat.Light" />

 <style name="Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat.Light" parent="Platform.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">false</item>

        <!-- Used by MediaRouter -->
        <item name="isLightTheme">true</item>
        <item name="selectableItemBackground">@drawable/abc_item_background_holo_light</item>
        <item name="selectableItemBackgroundBorderless">?attr/selectableItemBackground</item>
        <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha</item>
        <item name="dividerVertical">@drawable/abc_list_divider_mtrl_alpha</item>
        <item name="dividerHorizontal">@drawable/abc_list_divider_mtrl_alpha</item>

        <!-- Action Bar Styles -->
        <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.TabView</item>
        <item name="actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.TabBar</item>
        <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.TabText</item>
        <item name="actionButtonStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionButton</item>
        <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionButton.Overflow</item>
        <item name="actionOverflowMenuStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.PopupMenu.Overflow</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid</item>
        <item name="actionBarSplitStyle">?attr/actionBarStyle</item>
        <item name="actionBarWidgetTheme">@null</item>
        <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="actionBarSize">@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material</item>
        <item name="actionBarDivider">?attr/dividerVertical</item>
        <item name="actionBarItemBackground">?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Menu</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">?android:attr/textColorPrimaryDisableOnly</item>

        <!-- Action Mode -->
        <item name="actionModeStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionMode</item>
        <item name="actionModeBackground">@drawable/abc_cab_background_top_material</item>
        <item name="actionModeSplitBackground">?attr/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="actionModeCloseDrawable">@drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha</item>
        <item name="actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.CloseMode</item>
        <item name="actionModeCutDrawable">@drawable/abc_ic_menu_cut_mtrl_alpha</item>
        <item name="actionModeCopyDrawable">@drawable/abc_ic_menu_copy_mtrl_am_alpha</item>
        <item name="actionModePasteDrawable">@drawable/abc_ic_menu_paste_mtrl_am_alpha</item>
        <item name="actionModeSelectAllDrawable">@drawable/abc_ic_menu_selectall_mtrl_alpha</item>
        <item name="actionModeShareDrawable">@drawable/abc_ic_menu_share_mtrl_alpha</item>

        <!-- Dropdown Spinner Attributes -->
        <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar</item>

        <!-- Panel attributes -->
        <item name="panelMenuListWidth">@dimen/abc_panel_menu_list_width</item>
        <item name="panelMenuListTheme">@style/Theme.AppCompat.CompactMenu</item>
        <item name="panelBackground">@drawable/abc_menu_hardkey_panel_mtrl_mult</item>
        <item name="android:panelBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="listChoiceBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/abc_list_selector_holo_light</item>

        <!-- List attributes -->
        <item name="textAppearanceListItem">@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead</item>
        <item name="textAppearanceListItemSmall">@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead</item>
        <item name="listPreferredItemHeight">64dp</item>
        <item name="listPreferredItemHeightSmall">48dp</item>
        <item name="listPreferredItemHeightLarge">80dp</item>
        <item name="listPreferredItemPaddingLeft">16dip</item>
        <item name="listPreferredItemPaddingRight">16dip</item>

        <!-- Required for use of support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item.xml -->
        <item name="spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.DropDownItem.Spinner</item>
        <item name="dropdownListPreferredItemHeight">?attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall</item>

        <!-- Popup Menu styles -->
        <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.PopupMenu</item>
        <item name="textAppearanceLargePopupMenu">@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.Widget.PopupMenu.Large</item>
        <item name="textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu">@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.Widget.PopupMenu.Small</item>
        <item name="listPopupWindowStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.ListPopupWindow</item>
        <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.ListView.DropDown</item>

        <!-- SearchView attributes -->
        <item name="searchViewStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.SearchView</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownItemStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.DropDownItem.Spinner</item>
        <item name="textColorSearchUrl">@color/abc_search_url_text</item>
        <item name="textAppearanceSearchResultTitle">@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.SearchResult.Title</item>
        <item name="textAppearanceSearchResultSubtitle">@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.SearchResult.Subtitle</item>

        <!-- ShareActionProvider attributes -->
        <item name="activityChooserViewStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActivityChooserView</item>

        <!-- Toolbar styles -->
        <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar</item>
        <item name="toolbarNavigationButtonStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Button.Navigation</item>
        <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText</item>
        <item name="editTextBackground">@drawable/abc_edit_text_material</item>
        <item name="editTextColor">?android:attr/textColorPrimary</item>

        <!-- Color palette -->
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark_material_light</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary_material_light</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent_material_light</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">?android:attr/textColorSecondary</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">?attr/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/ripple_material_light</item>
        <item name="colorSwitchThumbNormal">@color/switch_thumb_normal_material_light</item>
        <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle</item>
        <item name="switchStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.Switch</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, that's *exactly* what I was looking for! Also thanks for the Android Studio tip, that'll help alot

Comment: I accepted right after i posted the comment but i went back to upvote you too :)

Comment: Thanks and cheers! Does it mean that you aren't using Android studio. If not then would suggest you to start using it to enjoy awesomeness along with some issues ;)

Comment: Oh, I mean I *am* using Android Studio. So your tip helps twice as much! I didn't know about that

Answer (score 3):

You find themes at address below:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/34bea73a6b2d6659f327272e4f482f9d86c1b592/appcompat/res/values/themes.xml

I think there are some more files like the above for other than appcompat themes etc. Also check R.styleable under android.support.v7.

Comment: According to the git log, the file seems never updated after the year of 2012. Am I missing something?