# How to add image instead of title text in android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-titlebar

[image]

I want to add this image instead of title text and default android image of action bar, like shown in image above.

Comment: Check this answer here. It might be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26439715/android-how-to-style-action-bar-with-pattern/26441088#26441088

Comment: Tried getActionBar().setIcon()?

Comment: Check [Customizing actionbar](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=custom+actionbar), you will sure get solution!

Answer (score 0):

From what I've tried for this matter, You can do it by making one layout that will act as the action bar, and then call it in every activity you have and set your Manifest. Here I give you clue on it and how to set it in manifest and your activity class:

1. Code your 'action bar layout', let's call it window_header.xml. Put it in your res>layout directory. Just make a layout that contain an imageview, set the layout's height as it will be your action bar height.
   You can also set the color and everything you want, just make it like a normal layout with the height you set.
2. In your Manifest, in the android:theme section, change it to looks like this:

> android:theme="@style/CustomTheme"

3. To accomplish it, you need a resource file which stating that it will use a custome style, here is my code of it:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <resources>
       <style name="CustomWindowTitleBackground">
           <item name="android:background">#323331</item>
       </style> 
       <style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme">
           <item name="android:windowTitleSize">35dip</item>
           <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/CustomWindowTitleBackground</item>
       </style>
   </resources>
   ```
4. And lastly, call it in your activity OnCreate method like this:

   ```
   requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
   getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.window_header);
   ImageView icon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon);
   this.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.browse);
   ```

Try it, a little bit of exploration and self inovation would done better. Hope it helps